# sed or awk: remove numbers after a symbol

Tags: awk, sed, delete

I would like to remove just the numbers and "_" after ">" symbol, for example:

```
>1_CR-B_CR56_t
MTKIIKFVYFMTIFISPNHHCPVYNCTHPKQPWCKLVRLQLLFHGSLIGLCDCI
>2_R-B_R46_t
MVEVTKLVNVMLIFLTLSPLVYDCQAYECELPFKPDCLMVEYSPQFVALRCGCV
>3000_N-N274_M
MVEVTKLVNVMLIFLTLFVYTDSDCQAYACELPFKPDCLMVEYAPQFFRLACGCV
```

Expected Results:

```
>CR-B_CR56_t
MTKIIKFVYFMTIFISPNHHCPVYNCTHPKQPWCKLVRLQLLFHGSLIGLCDCI
>R-B_R46_t
MVEVTKLVNVMLIFLTLSPLVYDCQAYECELPFKPDCLMVEYSPQFVALRCGCV
>N-N274_M
MVEVTKLVNVMLIFLTLFVYTDSDCQAYACELPFKPDCLMVEYAPQFFRLACGCV
```

I used `sed "s/>[0-9][_]//g"` but it removed ">" as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a slight modification from your `sed` command:

```
sed 's/^>[0-9]\+[_]/>/g'
```

the `s` is the sed *substitute* command, it searches for the string on the left hand side and replaces it with the string on the right hand side.  Instead of replacing it with nothing you can replace it with the `>` character that you would like to keep.

`^` is used to specify that the match should only start at the beginning of a newline

Additionally the `*` is being used to match more than a single digit.

Comment: thanks. I tried so many options, but not this one.

Comment: You might want the line-start anchor (`^`) as well. And `\+` instead of `*` for **one** or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{sub(/^>._|^>...._/,">")}1' file
>CR-B_CR56_t
MTKIIKFVYFMTIFISPNHHCPVYNCTHPKQPWCKLVRLQLLFHGSLIGLCDCI
>R-B_R46_t
MVEVTKLVNVMLIFLTLSPLVYDCQAYECELPFKPDCLMVEYSPQFVALRCGCV
>N-N274_M
MVEVTKLVNVMLIFLTLFVYTDSDCQAYACELPFKPDCLMVEYAPQFFRLACGCV
```

Answer (score 0):

```
command:sed 's/^>[0-9]\{1,9\}\_/>/g' filename
```

output

```
>CR-B_CR56_t
MTKIIKFVYFMTIFISPNHHCPVYNCTHPKQPWCKLVRLQLLFHGSLIGLCDCI
>R-B_R46_t
MVEVTKLVNVMLIFLTLSPLVYDCQAYECELPFKPDCLMVEYSPQFVALRCGCV
>N-N274_M
MVEVTKLVNVMLIFLTLFVYTDSDCQAYACELPFKPDCLMVEYAPQFFRLACGCV
```